# AWS Lambda, SQS, Subnet, Internet, multiple lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, subnet, private-subnet

I am new to AWS and bit confused. I use Claudia to deploy and NodeJS.

I need to make 3 Lambda functions:

1. This function needs to get jobs from DB, it needs to be private because of DB security. Then I need SQS to make a jobs query
2. Second function should execute each job 1-time FIFO style and return results.
3. 3rd function should get the results from the second Lambda function and store it again in DB.

Can someone please give me and advice how to do this:

- What kind of internet connections to use
- How to set up the query between 1st and second function
- How 3rd function will get the results from the second?

Comment: Have you tried implementing your plan? If so, what difficulties have you encountered? We'd love to assist, but you haven't really provided much information in your question. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Firstly I would like some help of how do I generate SQS from the 1st Lambda Function Results?

Comment: Are you saying that your Lambda function would push a message into an SQS Queue? In that case, you should create the queue first in SQS, then use the `SendMessage()` command to send a message to the queue. For example, if you are using Python, refer to: [SQS — boto](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/sqs.html)